# how do I yum remove an rpm [gssproxy] and not also remove dependencies [nfs-utils]

Tags: rhel, yum

I was given a security rule that says `gssproxy` must be removed.  When doing so it also removes `nfs-utils` as a dependency.  I need to keep `nfs-utils` to be able to nfs mount.  Is there a way to remove only `gssproxy` and if so how?  This is in RHEL 8.8.

At the very least I want to try the removal of just `gssproxy` and observe what the ramifications are.  This is on a test system.

Answer (score 0):

YUM/DNF won't let you do it, their purpose is to resolve and manage package dependencies and keep a consistent system.

You can rip the package out of the `rpm` database without removing any dependencies, but this is likely to prevent parts of `nfs-utils` from functioning correctly.  IIRC, the `nfs-secure` service has a dependency on the `gssproxy` service so that is likely to not work anymore and here could be other problems.

Make sure this is something you really want to do before you run it:

`rpm --erase --nodeps gssproxy`

Comment: And beware that gssproxy might come back if another package install (potentially just a patch) requires it as a dependency.